# What is the name of "use xxx" statement, and how to read that value?

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction(){
  "use asm"//what is this name
}

function getUseFromFunction(myFunction){//it should returns "use asm" string
  //???
}
```

Some page called it directive (for example w3schools), but I not found a relevant, general name. And I can't found a way to read it well from a function. I think parse the toString method result has a many possible error chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a *Directive Prologue* and is described on [page 237 of ECMA-262 (section 14.1.1)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (or page 257 if you use the PDF page number instead of the printed number).

It isn't possible to reliably read the value from JavaScript. It is intended to be processed by the underlying JS compiler.

Some JS engines will let you access the source code of a function via `myFunction.toString()`, at which point you can extract it by writing a JS parser to look for it with.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a directive, and basically all it does it tell the browser how to read/interpret the code. You can read more about it here, as the `use strict` mode is also a directive, but has more/clearer documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Edit: but you cannot read the value used by a function or any other scope unless you want to parse the source of the function or scope, which you should never need because it's a solution to a problem you should not have in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

it is a directive that indicates to the js-engine (i.e. browser) that the code inside the function can be further optimized, similar to `"use strict"`.
(see http://asmjs.org/ for more info)

`"use asm"` ist NOT the return value of `myFunction`

Comment: In my case the "use asm" expression is only an example, same as "use anything"